# Xslt to process bank account transaction

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am using xslt to format xml input data to html format.
Case : is that i have opening-balance value as an attribute in TRANSACTIONS node and list of transactions.
It's supposed that i print html table as following.
 first row is value of opening-balance
 second row is value of opening + AMOUNT @ first node in TRANSACTIONS.
 third row is value @ second row + AMOUNT @ second node in TRANSACTIONS.
And etc for rest rows

```
<results>
<TRANSACTIONS opening-balance="100">
    <TRANSACTION>
        <TYPE>DEBIT</TYPE>
        <AMOUNT>10</DR_CR_MARKER>
         <VALUE_DATE_1>20150726</VALUE_DATE_1>
    </TRANSACTION>
    <TRANSACTION>
        <TYPE>DEBIT</TYPE>
        <AMOUNT>20</DR_CR_MARKER>
        <VALUE_DATE_1>20150626</VALUE_DATE_1>
    </TRANSACTION>
    <TRANSACTION>
        <TYPE>DEBIT</TYPE>
        <AMOUNT>30</DR_CR_MARKER>
        <VALUE_DATE_1>20150826</VALUE_DATE_1>
    </TRANSACTION>
</TRANSACTIONS>
</results>
```

and my xslt to process this is

```
<xsl:template match="results">
<xsl:param name="opening-balance">
    <xsl:value-of select="TRANSACTIONS/@opening-balance"/>
</xsl:param>
    <xsl:for-each select="TRANSACTIONS/TRANSACTION">
        <xsl:sort select="VALUE_DATE_1"/>
        <tr style="background-color: yellow">
            <td>
                <!-- i want to print total amount value here -->
                <xsl:variable name="opening-balance" select="$opening-balance+amount" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$opening-balance"/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

i cannt do it by this code .
so, could you help me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sum` function here, together with the `preceding-sibling` axis to select all the previous transactions you wish to sum

```
<xsl:value-of select="$opening-balance + AMOUNT + sum(preceding-sibling::TRANSACTION/AMOUNT)"/>
```

However, if you are sorting your output, you can use this expression instead to select all the nodes with lower values

```
<xsl:value-of select="$opening-balance + sum(../TRANSACTION[VALUE_DATE_1 &lt;= current()/VALUE_DATE_1]/AMOUNT)"/>
```

So this adds the opening balance, the amount for the current transaction, and the sum from all the previous transactions.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="results">
    <xsl:param name="opening-balance" select="TRANSACTIONS/@opening-balance"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$opening-balance"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="TRANSACTIONS/TRANSACTION">
            <xsl:sort select="VALUE_DATE_1"/>
            <tr style="background-color: yellow">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$opening-balance + sum(../TRANSACTION[VALUE_DATE_1 &lt;= current()/VALUE_DATE_1]/AMOUNT)"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note this will only work all the `VALUE_DATE_1` amounts are different. If you have two `VALUE_DATE_1` with the same value, then you need to specify an additional criteria on which to sort.

Comment: Thanks, it works.but unfortunately i use sort for  <xsl:for-each> and this make calculation not accurate

Comment: Can you edit your question to show it using `xsl:sort` as currently there is no mention of sorting at all. Thank you!

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how this can be done.